# How to get Script Path from each Jenkins Jobs using Groovy Console Script/Jenkins API

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-api

**I have a requirement to fetch Script path from Jenkins Job .**

Please find the below screenshot to understand the requirement more clearly.

[image]

I have checked in google to get some Groovy Console Script which lists details of each Job.

By using the **jenkins.model.Jenkins.getJobNames()** method ,i was able to get all Jobs in Jenkins , but actually the requirement is to get the **Scriptpath** value, mentioned inside each those jobs.

Which Jenkins Class/method can provide those details or is any other way to fetch those details using Jenkins API?

By reading the **config.xml** for each job and getting the Scriptpath tag from it will also give me the information needed, But I was looking for a **REST method** or **Jenkins Groovy Script method** which can give me this Script path Information for each Job.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open your job configuration page.
2. Change the `configure` at the end of url to `config.xml` and press Enter
3. The new opening page loads xml content
4. Find Scriptpath value in tag `<scriptPath>xxxxxx</scriptPath>`

So you can send http requset to job's confim.xml url and parse the content to get the value programmatically

Comment: Yea !! As mentioned in the question, the Config file is providing the required information. But I was looking for a REST method or Jenkins Groovy Script method(like jenkins.model.Jenkins.getJobNames() method) which can give me this Script path Information for each Job.